# R get index satisty the condition

Tags: r

Given vector `x` as:

```
x = c(5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3)
```

I want to get the index of x, which x value is bigger than 7

The result I expect:

```
2, 3, 4
```

I have tried

```
Position[x >= 7, x]
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in Position[x >= 7, x] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Comment: `Position` is a function, but in your code, you suppose it is an object. You need to use `()` instead of `[]`. However, you need to define a function in order to use `Position`.

Comment: I think you just want `which(x>=7)`